# (Angular) Masonry How to get column index of element / next column

Tags: javascript, angularjs, masonry

We are implementing a keyboard navigation for Masonry elements for this we would need a way to get the element below another element in the same column. Is there a way to access this information (x + y for each item) via the masonry API (or better, AngularJS).

We could not find anything in the API / data fields and what is left an idea eis basically to actually read the x / y positions of the elements and reverse engineer this or change the masonry code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We opted to get the raw data, i.e. x and y locations on all widgets, and look in the same column for the ones above or below based on y coordinate, e.g.:

```
    aboveIdx = -1
    currentIdx = 0
    while (currentIdx < items.length)
      if(items[currentIdx].position.x is items[$scope.selectedCardIndex].position.x and
         items[currentIdx].position.y < items[$scope.selectedCardIndex].position.y)
        aboveIdx = currentIdx
      currentIdx += 1
    $scope.selectedCardIndex = aboveIdx
```